# R ggplot generates only one boxplot for different x values

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to generate a box plot with ggplot. I have generated a dataset with the following code:

```
names <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

data <- c(2,6,8,1,3,6,3,4,3,8,6,5)

frame <- data.frame(data, names)
```

I would like to have a box plot within one diagram for each value in `names`. But with the following code I only get a single boxplot:

```
ggplot(frame, aes(names,data)) + geom_boxplot()
```

What's my mistake?

Here you can see the diagram that I get:
[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need add one line of code convert names to factors as @Stephane Laurent mentioned.

```
frame$names <- as.factor(frame$names)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Convert `names` to a factor:

```
names <- factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))
```